# How to convert a date to long date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert a date(01-02-2019) to Wed, 02 Jan 2019 in javascript?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       var dealDate = 01-02-2019;
});
```

Comment: You can use Date.parse and then convert it on your own, see https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Or you can use small library like https://date-fns.org/ to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Date Constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [`Date.prototype.toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString):

> The `toDateString()` method returns the date portion of a Date object in **human readable form** in American English.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var dealDate = new Date('01-02-2019').toDateString();
  console.log(dealDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `new Date()` on that date value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dealDate = '01-02-2019';
  //replace all - to / to make it work on firefox
  dealDate = dealDate.replace(/-/g,'/'); 
  alert(new Date(dealDate).toDateString())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: alerts "Invalid Date" for me on Firefox.

Comment: @ChrisG it works now. Seems like we need to replace `-` with `/`

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string on `-` and then generate the `date` using Date constructor.

```js
var dealDate = '01-02-2019';
let [month, day, year] = dealDate.split('-').map(Number);
let date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
console.log(date.toDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

TO convert the date to in the format of month day, month day number and year use the below jquery. It will convert the current date to the exact format you asked for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dealDate = new Date();
alert(dealDate.toUTCString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your expected format is like [day][comma][date][month][year]. I split toDateString() and rearranged in expected format.

```js
 function formatedDate(d){
    var dt=new Date(d).toDateString().split(' ');
    return dt[0]+', '+dt[2]+' '+dt[1]+' '+dt[3]; //[Day][comma][date][month][year]
    }

    console.log(formatedDate('01-02-2019'))
```